# History of commands on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, logging

This query gives me the history of commands executed on SQL Server:

```
Select *
From
(
SELECT      deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
            dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
) x
```

When I added `Where x.Query LIKE '%Insert%'` I get bad results (I think that this is because of the cross join):

```
Select *
From
(
    SELECT      deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
                dest.TEXT AS [Query]
    FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
) x
Where x.Query LIKE '%Insert%'
```

How do I get the cross join to work properly on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by: "Bad results", but this works for me:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS dest 
WHERE dest.TEXT LIKE '%Insert%'
```