# How to generate script for my database and tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created several tables using the gui from SQL Server. Now I want to see the actual **"code"**. But I don't know where to find it.

For example, as I was right clicking "databases" and then choosing the "create table" option and filling in column names and the datatypes from the drop down menu, I assume there must be a `" CREATE TABLE Happy_Life (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER) "`  somewhere.

My question is where?

Comment: Right-click on the table, and choose `CREATE to->New query editor window` from the `Script as` submenu.

Comment: There're serveral ways.
Try ` cat ~/.mysql_history` to see command history or you can find .sql file in backup folder

Comment: @KienPham The OP isn't using MySQL.

Comment: @KenWhite You are god's gift to mankind.
First suggestion worked....

Comment: @KienPham: `cat ~/.mysql_history` won't do a thing if a) you're using SQL Server instead of MySQL, and b) not running on a *nix OS.

Comment: My bad. But backup folder contains some history files

Comment: This might help. Please try
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298283/history-of-commands-on-sql-server

Answer (score 4):

Right-Click on your table

1. Script Table As
2. Create To
3. New Query Editor Window
   [image]

Comment: Similar to this, you can generate scripts for all tables (and other objects like views, stored procedures, indexes, etc.) by right clicking on the database, and selecting Tasks -> Generate Scripts.

Answer (score 1):

To generate script of entire database & all database objects (Schema only or Schema with data) or script for only specific database objects like tables,views,stored procedures etc. The steps are as follows.

Right click on Database object -> Task -> Generate Script
[image]

Click on Next
[image]

Select The database object to script -> Next
[image]

Advanced -> Type of data to be script -> OK
[image]

Set file name with location -> Next
[image]

[image]

Finally click on Finish.

[image]